# How to use Promise.all() on arrays of different types?

Tags: typescript

Typescript 4.2.2

Given:

```
const firstPromises: Promise<First>[] = ...;
const secondPromises: Promise<Second>[] = ...;
return Promise.all([firstPromises, secondPromises]).
  then([first, second] => {
    // do something
  }
```

I expect `first` and `second` to be of type `First[]` and `Second[]` respectively. Instead, the output types remain as `Promise<First>[]` and `Promise<Second>[]`. Any ideas?

Comment: I think they should be Promise<First[]> and Promise<Second[]>

Comment: You are passing an array of arrays of promises instead of  an array of promises

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan In my case, I really did have two arrays of promises, not promises of an array.

Comment: Oh I see. Nested promises... I don't know why you need them but it sounds like trouble especially if it refers to some api call 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a *nested* array of promises to `Promise.all`. It doesn't know how to handle that, so it just passes it right through to `then` because it doesn't see any promises. It jsut sees an array, which is doesn't look inside of.

But you can just call `Promise.all` on each sub array of promises to package that up into a single promise. Then pass each of those to `Promise.all` to create a promise for both sets.

```
const getBool = async () => true
const getString = async () => "foo"

function foo() {
    const firstPromises: Promise<boolean>[] = [getBool(), getBool()];
    const secondPromises: Promise<string>[] = [getString(), getString()];
    return Promise.all([
        Promise.all(firstPromises),
        Promise.all(secondPromises)
    ]).then(([first, second]) => {
        // first: boolean[]
        // second: string[]
    })
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygIRCANjAvDAhhATzGBgAoBKbAPhigCcBXBAKFElkSgGV6BLMONjyFiZSlhoAiAGZpJzZtIbEovcDFkgKMAN7MYBmG2gbedaAAU6IALa8ICCAC4YV2-YQAeAEZp0CXDAqAG0AXSFgzlQMCgAaeCRo9ApQgG59Q2NYBzYAEzc7B2dXa0KvaDp+OBDwnEikHkqBOITuPmbyNIyDOiQGOjAS9wcAOlx0ZODuwwMCjzGJ0mkzS1KPCHJY6Zm50fHknPB8taLyadDyEagACwQwUlJg5fMoeMOwXIvqXW3DAHo-qYXi5fBgAmAwr8DACYO9ci4KlVITMAL5nFHMIA)